# Angular JS 1.5 Component html content shown as commented out in browser

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to the Angular world, and while trying out a few things, I am basically stuck with a basic angular component problem.

So the idea is to simply add a custom element called "cast-tile" to the page which would be loaded by angular as a component. But the browser somehow shows the code in ng-repeat as commented.

My code is below

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.1" data-semver="1.6.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>My Favourite X-Men's</h1>

  <sample-component data="Jack"></sample-component> <!-- this works -->

  <cast-tile cast="mutants"></cast-tile> <!-- does not work -->

</body>

</html>
```

Script.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mutants = [{
    name: 'Wolverine',
    actor: 'Hujh Jackman',
    image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0e/a3/3b/0ea33b4fc6e96eb684d6eb9f9f66482d.jpg'
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Cyclops',
    actor: 'James Marsden',
    image: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/xmenmovies/images/d/d3/Cyclops_04.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/350?cb=20140330215941'
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Storm',
    actor: 'Hally Barry',
    image: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/xmenmovies/images/a/a7/Storm_xmen3.JPG/revision/latest?cb=20120128061314'
  }];
});

myApp.component("castTile", {
  templateUrl: "myTemplate.html",
  bindings: {
    cast: '='
  },
  restrict: 'E',
  controller: function(){

  }
});

myApp.component("sampleComponent", {
  template: '<h3>Hello {{ $ctrl.data }}</h3>',
  bindings: {
    data: '@'
  },
  restrict: 'AE'
});
```

and finally, myTemplate.html

```
<div class="tiles" ng-repeat="mutant in mutants">
  <h3>{{ mutant.name }}</h3>
  <p>{{ mutant.actor }}</p>
  <img width="100" height="150" ng-src="{{ mutant.image }}" />
</div>
```

The browser console does not show any errors.

[Please find the code on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MGgThVvK3XUfpVi0fzlk?p=preview)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the binding that contains `mutants` list is called `cast` in your component `castTile`. Also, you need to prefix `cast` with `$ctrl.`, as you correctly did it in `sampleComponent`:

```
<div class="tiles" ng-repeat="mutant in $ctrl.cast">
```

should work ;-)